# Find the source code file in <iframe>

Tags: jsp, jsf, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` tag with `scr="name.jsf"`. Now I want to find where is this source code placed but looking into the source I only see there is only *.jsp file. This is a legacy project that I begin to join in. Have no experience on JavaServer Face.

Could anyone help me to find the source or at least how file.jsp convert to file.jsf?

Any idea or document is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check below tags in the web.xml file of your web project

```
  <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

You can check from `<servlet-mapping />` tags are responsible for calling JSF lifecycle or JSF provided default servlet in your case may be you already extend JSF servlet and created your own servlet.

So no one converting JSP to JSF URL or Vice-Versa .This all magic done by deployment descriptor or `web.xml` .

In my case we have following entry in web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But all the webpages have extension `*.xhtml`(Like a.xhtml,abc.xhtml,xyz.xhtml) ,so if you will try `http://localhost:8080/abc.xhtml` it will not work but when you will try with `http://localhost:8080/abc.jsf` OR `http://localhost:8080/faces/abc.xhtml`  it will work because `<servlet-mapping />` have `<url-pattern/>` defined.SO when that pattern will match then only JSF servlet or your design servlet will fire.

Comment: @user3422401 If your question clear please accept the answer